# How to create more squares but keep the grid size intact in Etch a Sketch without CSS grid

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I am finalizing Etch a Sketch for The Odin Project. I am trying to duplicate the squares, using only flexbox and keep the grid size intact but after looping the square the grid gets longer.
I have tried to recall the `resizeGrid` function using the `userInput` as parameter when clicking the button but its  not working.
Most of the answers I found are using CSS grid but I have not learned it yet and the exercise say I should use only flexbox.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated. I really can't see what I should do.

```js
// All the divs are created through DOM
// Main container
function createDiv() {
  const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
  mainDiv.setAttribute("id","mainDiv");
}
createDiv();

const size = 16;
// Grid container
function createGrid(size) {
  const mainGrid = document.createElement("div");
  mainDiv.appendChild(mainGrid);
  mainGrid.setAttribute("id","mainGrid");
}
createGrid(size);

// Function to create individual square and change its color while hovering
function createChild() {
  const childDiv = document.createElement("div");
  mainGrid.appendChild(childDiv);
  childDiv.setAttribute("id", "childDiv");
  // Event for changing colors while hovering over the squares
  childDiv.addEventListener(
    "mouseenter",
    (event) => {
      event.target.style.background = "black";
    }
  );
}

//Function to loop the squares
function createLoop() {
  for (i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    createChild();
  }
}
createLoop();

// Function to create buttons, change its color and get user value when button is clicked
function createButton() {
  // create button for changing grid size
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  mainDiv.appendChild(button);
  button.setAttribute("id","button");
  button.textContent = "Change grid size"; 

  // event to get user's value through prompt
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    userInput = prompt("Please insert desired size, between 1-100");
    if (userInput > 100) {
      alert("Value too high, please retry")
    } else {
      clearGrid();
    }
    resizeGrid(userInput);
  });
}
createButton();

//Function to create eraser and event
function createEraser() {
  // create button for eraser
  const eraserBtn = document.createElement("button");
  mainDiv.appendChild(eraserBtn);
  eraserBtn.setAttribute("id","eraserBtn");
  eraserBtn.textContent = "Eraser";

  // event for eraser
  eraserBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  })
}
createEraser()

//Function to clear color
function clearColor() {
  // create button for clearing grid
  const clearBtn = document.createElement("button");
  mainDiv.appendChild(clearBtn);
  clearBtn.setAttribute("id","clearBtn");
  clearBtn.textContent = "Clear";

  // event to clear grid on click
  clearBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mainGrid.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
      child.style.backgroundColor = null;
    });
  });
}
clearColor();

// Function to clear grid
function clearGrid() {
  while(mainGrid.firstChild) {
    mainGrid.removeChild(mainGrid.firstChild);
  }
}

// Function to change grid size
function resizeGrid(userInput) {
  for (i = 0; i < userInput * userInput; i++) {
    createChild();
  }
  
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #1a759f;
}
#mainDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}
#mainGrid {
    color: #d9ed92;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 640px;
    max-width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    max-height: 640px;
    background-color: #d9ed92;
}
#childDiv {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #d9ed92;
    border-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 1 1;
}

#button, #clearBtn, #eraserBtn {
    background-color: black;
    border: solid;
    color: white;
    padding:  15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    width: 132px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what 'looping the square' means here - could you describe a bit more what is going wrong as at the moment I seem to be able to 'draw' OK.

Comment: Hey so when you click the "change grid" button you get a prompt and according to that value 'userInput' i want it to be used in the resizeGrid function to change how many squares are. thats why i used a loop function. the initial squares are 16x16 (defa'ult). so if the number is 10 it will be 10x10 in the grid and look bigger, but if the input is higher there will be more squares but smaller, without changing the size of the `mainGrid`

Comment: When the value is higher than 16 the main grid expands but i want to keep it the same size

Comment: When the user gives a new size where do you get rid of the existing squares before creating new ones?

Comment: function clearGrid() is removing the existing squares

Comment: I have also noticed that the squares only stay 16 per row when higher, how can i make them change as well?

Comment: When the user gives too high a number you don't clear the squares but you do create new ones (I realise this isn't the main problem!)

Comment: You don't seem to be resizing the squares - so they stay at 16 per row.

Comment: the squares were clearing very well when insterting new ones. i made it work ty

Answer (score 0):

Made it work! My scenario was a bit different, since I have created all elements through DOM they were a bit hard to reach, so I had to actually redeclare the `childDiv` (squares) when calling the function to change grid size. Also calculated the size with flex-basis. This was a great opportunity to learn DOM and how global/local variables work! If anyone is in the same situation I hope this helps you

```js
// All the divs are created through DOM
// Main container
function createDiv() {
  const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
  mainDiv.setAttribute("id", "mainDiv");
}
createDiv();

// Grid container
function createGrid() {
  const mainGrid = document.createElement("div");
  mainDiv.appendChild(mainGrid);
  mainGrid.setAttribute("id", "mainGrid");
}
createGrid();

// Function to create individual square and change its color while hovering
let j = 1;
function createChild() {
  const childDiv = document.createElement("div");
  mainGrid.appendChild(childDiv);
  childDiv.setAttribute("class", "childDiv");
  // Event for changing colors while hovering over the squares
  childDiv.addEventListener(
    "mouseenter",
    (event) => {
      event.target.style.background = "black";
    }
  );
}

//Function to loop the squares
const size = 16;
function createLoop() {
  for (i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    createChild();
  }
}
createLoop();

// Function to create buttons, change its color and get user value when button is clicked
function createButton() {
  // create button for changing grid size
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  mainDiv.appendChild(button);
  button.setAttribute("id", "button");
  button.textContent = "Change grid size";

  // event to get user's value through prompt
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    j = 1;
    userInput = prompt("Please insert desired size, between 1-100");
    if (userInput > 100) {
      alert("Value too high, please retry")
    } else {
      clearGrid();
    }
    resizeGrid(userInput);
  });
}
createButton();

//Function to create eraser and event
function createEraser() {
  // create button for eraser
  const eraserBtn = document.createElement("button");
  mainDiv.appendChild(eraserBtn);
  eraserBtn.setAttribute("id", "eraserBtn");
  eraserBtn.textContent = "Eraser";

  // event for eraser
  eraserBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  })
}
createEraser();

//Function to clear color
function clearColor() {
  // create button for clearing grid
  const clearBtn = document.createElement("button");
  mainDiv.appendChild(clearBtn);
  clearBtn.setAttribute("id", "clearBtn");
  clearBtn.textContent = "Clear";

  // event to clear grid on click
  clearBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    mainGrid.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
      child.style.backgroundColor = null;
    });
  });
}
clearColor();

// Function to clear grid
function clearGrid() {
  while (mainGrid.firstChild) {
    mainGrid.removeChild(mainGrid.firstChild);
  }
}

// Function to change grid size
function resizeGrid(userInput) {
  for (i = 0; i < userInput * userInput; i++) {
    // redeclare childDiv
    // had difficulty to access the element already created with DOM, so this actually worked
    const childDiv = document.createElement("div");
    mainGrid.appendChild(childDiv);
    childDiv.setAttribute("class", "childDiv");

    //calculate size of squares each time grid changes size
    childDiv.style.flexBasis = `calc(100% / ${userInput})`;

    //redeclare event listener for changing color when hovering over
    childDiv.addEventListener(
      "mouseenter",
      (event) => {
        event.target.style.background = "black";
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* background-color: #1a759f;*/
  }
  
  #mainDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  #mainGrid {
    color: #d9ed92;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 640px;
    max-width: 640px;
    height: 640px;
    max-height: 640px;
    background-color: #d9ed92;
  }
  
  .childDiv {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #d9ed92;
    border-color: white;
    flex-basis: calc(100%/16);
  }
  
  #button,
  #clearBtn,
  #eraserBtn {
    background-color: black;
    border: solid;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    width: 132px;
  }
```